# MySQL / PHP background image URL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to setup a basic script to display the top 5 of votes from a MySQL table. I have it displaying in the order I would like but I can't seem to add a background image. I want it to look like this:

[image: What I am after]

But the output I'm getting is:

[image: What I actually get]

My code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Top 5 Voters</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<?php

   $server = "localhost";
   $dbuser = "xxx";
   $dbpass = "xxxx";
   $dbname = "xxxx";

mysql_connect($server, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes_hub_galtotals ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 5");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo '<ul class="serverList">';
        echo '<li class="server"><a href=""><span class="serverIcon" style="background-image: url("http://i.fishbans.com/helm/'.$row['IGN'].'/48");"></span>'.$row['IGN'].' ('.$row['votes'].')</a></li>';
    echo "</ul>";

    ; }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Even if I set it up as a static image it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `vardump($row)`? what was its output? It seems to me that it is either a simple wrong image path issue or incorrect style of span issue.

Comment: Make a minimally reproducible example, and put the code here.

Comment: Have you checked if the style was applied on the span where you are trying to set the background image ? And why can't you just use a <img> tag instead of using a span and setting a background image to it  ?

Comment: We prefer code to appear in the question here, formatted with markdown. I've moved your images to our usual CDN too - if you could do questions this way in future, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at your network panel in your browser, to see if image requests are being made, and whether they are correctly named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you query is correct and your list has the correct order. Another thing is that its better if you have a complete list so put the ul before and after the while loop that you have a complete list after the iteration.

```
echo '<ul class="serverList">';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo '<li class="server"><a href=""><span class="serverIcon" style="background-image: url("http://i.fishbans.com/helm/'.$row['IGN'].'/48");"></span>'.$row['IGN'].' ('.$row['votes'].')</a></li>';       
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

So the image is not shown because the path is not correct or the element is not visible.

You set the image as background image. Its a span and its possble that you have not set the height and width for that element and thats why its not shown. use an `<img` element to show the image.

And the last one is that the `mysql` functions are deprecated and you should use `mysqli` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What would be the code if i use the <img> tag?

Comment: instead of the spam with the background image use an image tag to show the image.

Comment: @Stony: `s/spam/span/`, hah! `;-)`

Comment: Sorry ja i ment the span :D and not spam.